# Integrate My Module having Own DB in Another App

Tags: java, android, aar

I have a Notes App which contain DB, I need to use this Notes App as lib or module in My two parent apps, how can I use this in my two apps?

**AAR:**

If I am using .aar means is there possibility to create or store Database in aar module.

**Sub Module:**

if I go for sub module I need to create table in each projects.

**Individual APP:**

If I go for individual app,How I share my DB details.

Comment: Can't you provide **your library** db as API methods to interact with your **App modules**?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the best option for you to using Content provider.

> However, content providers are primarily intended to be used by other
>   applications, which access the provider using a provider client
>   object. Together, providers and provider clients offer a consistent,
>   standard interface to data that also handles inter-process
>   communication and secure data access.
>
> Typically you work with content providers in one of two scenarios; you
>   may want to implement code to access an existing content provider in
>   another application, or you may want to create a new content provider
>   in your application to share data with other applications.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics

After you created a content provider in your Notes App other apps can access by content resolver. This is totally similar way as you can access bookmarks or contacts on Android.

---

One more suggestion: don't forget to take care about security as well if you want to share only between your apps.

> If you are using a content provider for sharing data between only your
>   own apps, it is preferable to use the android:protectionLevel
>   attribute set to signature protection. Signature permissions do not
>   require user confirmation, so they provide a better user experience
>   and more controlled access to the content provider data when the apps
>   accessing the data are signed with the same key.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#ContentProviders